# Point of Artifact Repositories For Internal Code

Tags: continuous-integration, nexus, artifactory, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

Imagine for a cloud based solution, a good portion of the deployed code is developed internally. My question is what is the point of using an Artifact Repository for internal code where you could always build whatever version directly from the source code?

In other words, doesn't it make more sense to spend the time on the build server to facilitate ease pf building desired artifact versions from the code vs adding an Artifact Repository like Nexus to feed build artifacts to deployments?

Answer (score 2):

In theory yes, if you can be certain

- everything that went into an artifact is checked in such as sources, data files
- the exact environment (OS, compiler, linker, tools) used to built your artifact can be restored perfectly (snapshot of virtual machine)
- nothing was forgotten

**EDIT** 
In practice, as Mark O'Conner notes, even then two builds will normaly not be identical because they typically include timestamps and checksums depending on the former. You would have to somehow manually fix those during the build or somehow exactly reproduce time and timing on your build computer.

Otherwise you might face the situation that you can not (exactly) rebuild a certain Artifact. I prefer to have everything published to be stored in safe place.

Comment: Each time you rebuild the same revision the resultant file has a different file checksum. This makes it impossible to be absolutely certain the same revision has been deployed to two different machines. Reusing the same binary from an artifact repository solves this problem. Secondly it's common for open source projects to publish a jar containing the source code alongside the published artifact. This enables a 3rd party to verify both source and binary issued (and signed) by the original developer.

Answer (score 1):

The [Continuous Delivery](http://martinfowler.com/delivery.html) book calls the practice of building a binary more than once an antipattern:

> This antipattern violates two important principles. The ﬁrst is to
>   keep the de-ployment pipeline efﬁcient, so the team gets feedback as
>   soon as possible. Recompiling violates this principle because it
>   takes time, especially in large systems. The second principle is to
>   always build upon foundations known to be sound. The binaries that get
>   deployed into production should be exactly the same as those that went
>   through the acceptance test process—and indeed in many pipeline
>   im-plementations, this is checked by *storing hashes* of the binaries at
>   the time they are created and verifying that the binary is identical
>   at every subsequent stage in the process.

Binary equality checking via hash may also be important for auditing purposes in highly regulated domains.